# Error 2147012858 when doing a SOAP post to an https-based webservice using MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0

Tags: asp.net, iis, xmlhttprequest

Im trying to make a post to an https-based webservice using classic ASP, and it works, but most strange is that sometimes (randomly) it returns an error:

"The host name in the certificate is invalid or does not match"

When the page returns this error, after some time (minutes), it starts working fine again without doing anything.

```
Dim Result
Dim SoapRequest
Set SoapRequest = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")

Dim myXML 
Set myXML = CreateObject("MSXML.DOMDocument")
myXML.Async=False
SoapRequest.Open "POST", sUrl, False
SoapRequest.setRequestHeader "Content-Type","text/xml; charset=utf-8"
SoapRequest.setRequestHeader "SOAPAction", """http://tempuri.org/" & sMethod & """"
SoapRequest.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "BASIC " & Base64Encode(Request.ServerVariables("AUTH_USER")&":"&Request.ServerVariables("AUTH_PASSWORD"))   

Dim DataToSend
DataToSend = GetEnvelop(sMethod, params)

SoapRequest.Send DataToSend

If myXML.load(SoapRequest.responseXML) Then
    Dim Node
    Set Node = myXML.documentElement.selectSingleNode("//" & sMethod & "Result")
    Result =  Node.Text

    Set Node = Nothing
Else
    Result =  getXML("Response", "1", "Error calling WebService: " & sUrl & ", WebMethod: " & sMethod & " xml response: " & SoapRequest.responseXML, "0")   
End If
Set SoapRequest = Nothing
Set myXML = Nothing
```

Comment: which type of certificate you are using and what is yoyr site bindings?

Comment: I dont know the type of certificate because it's managed by the system administrator, the bindings reference to the url that I am pointing to.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, the problem was the bindings, two sites pointing to the same domain, so the balancer made the thing work sometimes. Hopefully now its working fine! :))))